# Превышено время выполнения в задаче "Забавная последовательность"

Tags: c++, оптимизация, олимпиада

На [acmp.ru](https://acmp.ru) я столкнулся с [этой](http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=996) задачей:

> *(Время: 1 сек. Память: 16 Мб)*
>
> Определим последовательность a<sub>i</sub> следующим образом:
> a<sub>1</sub> = 1, a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n - 1</sub> + 3, если число n
> уже встречалось в последовательности a, и a<sub>n</sub> =
> a<sub>n - 1</sub> + 2, иначе. Нетрудно видеть, что первые 8 членов
> этой последовательности таковы: 1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 18.
>
> Ваша задача вычислить a<sub>n</sub>.
>
> **Входные данные**: Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>).
>
> **Выходные данные**: В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите a<sub>n</sub>.

Мой алгоритм был следующий:

- Создаём массив int a[100001] - наша последовательность.
- Создаём массив bool w[100001] - место, где мы храним информацию о том, было ли число i в последовательности.
- `a[1] = 1; w[1] = true;`
- `i От 2 до N {` 
       `если w[i] == true то a[i] = a[i - 1] + 3;` 
      `иначе a[i] = a[i - 1] + 2;` 
      `w[a[i]] = true;` 
  `}`
- Вывод a[n].

Вот код, написанный по этому алгоритму:

```
#include <iostream>
int w[100002], a[100002], n;
int main()
{
    w[1] = true;
    a[1] = 1;
    std::cin >> n;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        if(w[i] == true){
            a[i] = a[i - 1] + 3;
        }
        else a[i] = a[i - 1] + 2;
        w[a[i]] = true;
    }
    std::cout << a[n];
}
```

Проблема в том, что у меня ошибка `Time limit exceeded`(выполнение программы около 1,4 секунд). Пока что я не могу придумать алгоритм быстрее.

Как я могу оптимзировать программу? Есть ли какие-то формулы или алгоритмы для этого?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Случаи, они всякие бывают...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int w[100002] = {0,1}, a = 1, n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        a += 2;
        if(w[i]) a ++;
        if (a <= 100000) w[a] = 1;
    }
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

На размер:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int w[100002] = {0,1}, a = 1, n, i = 1;
    std::cin >> n;
    while(i < n)
        w[(a += w[++i]?3:2) < 100001 ? a : 0] = 1;
    std::cout << a;
}
```

Comment: Довольно таки олимпиадное решение :)

Comment: Нет, там они любят маленький размер, а не скорость... А на размер - лучше так, как в обновленном ответе второй вариант...

Comment: Я про размер и говорил. Я у себя сократил примерно как у вас во втором варианте,  только вместо `while` у меня `for` и вместо `if` тернарный оператор. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Я еще больше сократил код.  1. В строчке с переменными меняем размер `w` на 300002. Убираем присваивание значений `a` и первых двух переменных `w`. `i` присваиваем `2`. Переносим эту строчку с переменными наверх, перед `main()`. 2. В начале `main()` добавляем страшную строчку `a = w[1] = 1;`.  3. Условие цикла меняем на  `--n`, а из тела убираем `< 100001 ? a : 0`. Меняем `w[++i]` на `w[i++]`.  Код сократился на 10 символов.

Comment: Ну неправильно же...

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет, ну код работает правильно. Вы тоже все верно сказали. Но к сожалению, галочку можно поставить только одному человеку.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> int w[100002], a[100002], n;
> ```

```
int w[300002], a[100002], n;
```

Comment: Да, оно зашло. Но не могли ли вы немного подробнее объяснить, чем увеличение размера массива повлияло на скорость?

Comment: Я разобрался, и понял ошибку. Спасибо за помощь!